# f# function to calculate n! faculty

Tags: recursion, f#

I am trying to write a function (fac : n:int -> int), that calculate N! faculty using recursion. But i got something very wrong. hope you can help

```
let rec factorial (fac : int -> int)  = 
    if  fac = 0 then 1 
    else fac * factorial (n-1)
let num = factorial 6
printfn "%A" num
printfn "%A" factorial
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing 'very' wrong with your function but two issues:

- `factorial` needs to return an `int` and not take a function from `int` to `int`:
  `let rec factorial (fac : int) : int  =`
- the recursive call should pass `fac-1` instead of `n-1`:
  `else fac * factorial (fac-1)`

`let rec factorial (fac : int) : int  = 
    if  fac = 0 then 1 
    else fac * factorial (fac-1)
let num = factorial 6
printfn "%A" num // 720`